# Can’t find variable: navigation error when trying to navigate inside from inside the stack navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've added a header button and I'd like to go to a specific screen in my app when I click on that button, here's the code:

```
function ActionBarIcon(props) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Image
        source={{uri : 'https://static.thenounproject.com/png/261370-200.png'}}
        style={{ width: 30, height: 30, marginRight : 15 }} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Orders">

        <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={HomePage} options = {{
          headerRight : props => <ActionBarIcon {...props}
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('Create Order')
          }} />
        }}/>

        <Stack.Screen name="Order Details" component={DetailsPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Create Order" component={CreateOrderPage} />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

As you can see, I want to go to create order page, when the header button is clicked but I'm getting an error saying "Can’t find variable: navigation". I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: did u try to put a return after Oprions ?

Comment: @yesIamFaded hey umm, I'm kinda new to react native and I'm not sure how to do what you said, could you write some could and show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must not be getting navigation inside headerRight, so you may try the below suggestion

```
 <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={HomePage} options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
      headerRight: props => <ActionBarIcon {...props}
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('Create Order') 
          }} />
    })}

    />
```

Comment: Hey, just tried but I'm getting another error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: Great to hear that. Thanks :)